# android studio runtimeexception stub

Tags: android

I am a complete newbie to Android Studio and follow a Tutorial right now. The Code of the tutorial is this:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);

        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                EditText firstNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstNumEditText);
                EditText secondNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondNumEditText);
                TextView resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);

                int num1 = Integer.parseInt(firstNum.toString());
                int num2 = Integer.parseInt(secondNum.toString());
                int result = num1 + num2;

                resultTextView.setText(result + "");

            }
        });




    }
}
```

When I Try to debug I get an error at this line "  int num2 = Integer.parseInt(secondNum.toString());"

I make a simple app that just adds 2 ints that were input into an edit text field.
When the error occurs the loop class opens and it says that API 30 was not found when I try to download it it does say that there are no resources,
Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: So I did a quick search on _How to get INT from Edittext_. And here is what I found:
`Integer.parseInt(num2.getText().getString())`

Answer (score 0):

toString() in EditText is not returning its text. Instead you should use

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(firstNum.getText().toString());
```

and the same for the second editText